# Wordpress: How to make random posts excluding current and from chosen date

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to have 5 random posts on post page (http://7cuteoutfits.com/2015/07/08/suits-rachel-z-office-fashion/) excluding current post. Random posts should be on chosen dates (for example posts from last 2 months until yesterday )
I added a few lines of code to single.php of my wordpress and now have 5 random posts. So I need to modify the code so that it will meet my requirements (above). I think it's 2 more lines, I'll be very thankful if you help.

```
<ul>
<?php
 $currentID = get_the_ID();
 $args = array(  'posts_per_page' => 5, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args);
foreach ( $rand_posts as $post ) : 
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use WP_Query for that.

```
global $post;
$args = array(
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)
'orderby'   => 'rand'
'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'after'     => 'January 1st, 2015',
        'before'    => array(
            'year'  => 2015,
            'month' => 07,
            'day'   => 9,
        ),
        'inclusive' => true,
    ),
),
'posts_per_page' => 5,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This query orders randomly posts between today (inclusive) and Jan. 1st 2015
I haven't tested the snippet here, so please let me know if it does not work for you.

More info on WP_query and its usage (also for date parameters) [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters)

Once you query with WP_Query, you have to

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

just as you are already doing.

**EDIT:**

To show the post content, you can call

```
the_content()
```

to print it directly, or

```
get_the_content()
```

to get it as a return value. Then you can handle the printing later with the HTML markup you desire.

Comment: Thank you so much. I forgot smth - I'd like to show not only headlines but also the posts (its content). Would you be so kind to help me with that also? :)

Comment: Add `post__not_in => array($post->ID)` to exclude the current the current post - you may need to called `global $post;` before your query to get that value.

Comment: I have modified the answer with regards to the post content.